# Checking 3rd Normal Form from Functional Dependencies

Tags: relational-database, database-normalization

I have a question about determining whether a relation is in 3rd Normal Form based on functional dependencies.

`R = {A,B,C,D,E}`
`A -> B`
`BC -> E`
`ED -> A`

From this, I determined the candidate keys to be:
`{ACD},{BCD},{CDE}`
Wikipedia says that a relation is in 3rd Normal Form if, for each functional dependency X->Y, it meets at least one of the following requirements:
1. Y is a subset of X
2. X is a superkey
Y is a subset of K for some key K

My work: `A -> B` satisfies 3 because of the key `{BCD}`, `BC->E` satisfies 3 because of `{CDE}`, and `CD -> A` satisfies 3 because of `{ACD}`.

Is this the correct way of interpreting those rules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`A -> B` expresses a functional dependency. But these

R<sub>1</sub> = {**A**,B}
R<sub>2</sub> = {**B,C**,E}
R<sub>3</sub> = {**E,D**,A}

express relations. (I'm assuming you meant us to take these as the relations you got from decomposing R.)

Normal forms apply to relations; they don't apply to functional dependencies. It doesn't make any sense to say "`A -> B` is in 3NF", or "A determines B is in 3NF".

So R<sub>1</sub> = {**A**,B} is a relation. It doesn't "satisfy rule 3 because of the key {B,C,D}". It can't, because {B,C,D} isn't in R<sub>1</sub>.

Those rules have to do with the candidate keys of the relations that result from decomposing R, not with the candidate keys of R itself.

**Later . . .** I see I made an incorrect assumption. You're trying to *evaluate* R, not decompose it. In that case your reasoning is correct, and R is in 3NF. You could also conclude that R is in 3NF because there are no non-prime attributes. Since there are no non-prime attributes, the right-hand side of every FD must be part of a candidate key.

But R is not in BCNF. (Or 4NF, or 5NF.)  Can you fix that?

Comment: I understand that, I'm trying to decide whether R is in 3NF, given those dependencies, and using the candidate keys I derived.  I think R is actually in 3NF because there don't seem to be any transitive dependencies...can you confirm this?

Comment: Ah, I see. I misunderstood you. I didn't realize you were trying to *evaluate* R instead of decomposing R. So yes, R is in 3NF, and your reasoning is correct. You could also say it's in 3NF because there are no non-prime attributes. That is, every column is part of a super key, so the right-hand side of every FD must be part of a super key. But it's not in BCNF. (Or 4NF or 5NF.)